# cakephp 3.x - $this->Auth->identify() isn't work(return false), while I trying from mobile application

Tags: android, ios, cakephp

I've done user login from web. It's working good. But, I'm using the same method for login from mobile applications[`Android`, IOS].

Request :

```
Array
(
    [Users] => Array
        (
            [username] => username
            [password] => password
        )

)

$this->Auth->identify();
```

But it's return false only from mobile applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by given way.

`$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password'=> 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);`

These code was given from **initialize()** method of **AppController.php**  file